# Any known vulnerabilities for thttpd 2.25b 29dec2003

Tags: linux, debian

Quick question, having trouble finding any information online relating to that specific year for the given version thttpd 2.25b 29dec2003. Need to explain what vulnerabilities this may have had, if it had any at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the following are the three public vulnerabilities listed for  thttpd -  tiny/turbo/throttling HTTP server  version 2.25b of 29dec2003

1. CVE-2006-4248
2. CVE-2006-1079
3. CVE-2006-1078

Further details can be looked up against these CVE numbers from any vulnerability database.